# Is there minimum stay requirement for Singapore EP holders?

Tags: singapore

I work for a company and already hold an Employment Pass (EP).

Due to the nature of the work i have to be outside of Singapore most of the time and fly in quite frequently for day or two.

Is there any minimum stay requirement for EP holder in Singapore? I do not want to have any problems with the Ministry of Manpower (MOM) but i will need to be outside of Singapore for multiple months at a time.

Comment: Is your job based in Singapore https://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits/employment-pass/eligibility?

Comment: Yes it is, i'm now fulltime in singapore, and i already have the EP, what im asking is if i just leave singapore while having EP is there some time after which MOM will be upset with me having EP? my company is fine with maintaining my EP,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but as far as I know there is **no residence requirement for holding an EP**: all that matters is that you're regularly paid in Singapore.  I previously worked in Singapore in a near-100% travel job and never had any issues with this.

Until 2020, Singapore even had tax breaks for frequent travellers:
https://www.iras.gov.sg/irashome/Schemes/Individuals/Not-Ordinarily-Resident--NOR--Scheme/